# mandatory tests with SPO/Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, training, microsoft-forms

is there a way to create a mandatory security training with SPO/Forms?
All users should be forced to go through a regular IT security training with a short test at the end. Is there a way/policy to make this training mandatory?
Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such policy to mandatory filled in security training list in SharePoint online.

More information about SharePoint Online Security for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/sharepoint-security-a-team-effort

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/sharepoint-file-access-policies?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks for your answer. What I am looking for is more a technical solution to provide a questionnaire/test with ITL security topics and making sure that all users have to go through it. I can create a questionnaire in MS Form, send the link to all users, but I have no control, that all users go through it. Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround, may be you could set unique permission on the questionnaire form list, has no permission for the site, if the user complete the test, then use flow to change the permission to make them access sites